# Android WebView Shows Site Differently Than Chrome

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

My app has a list view with data from an RSS feed.  When a row is selected it then shows that article in a web view.  It loads the page but it doesn't load the full mobile site like Chrome does.  I'm putting screenshots of an article loaded in the web view of my app and the same page in Chrome.  Any ideas?

Here it is in Chrome:
[image]

Here it is in my web view:
[image]

```
package com.example.kyfbtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebBrowser extends Activity {
    WebView web;
    ProgressBar prgPageLoading;
    ImageButton btnBack, btnForward;
    Button btnShare;
    String myURL;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.webbrowser);

        Intent iGet = getIntent();
        myURL = iGet.getStringExtra("myURL");

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        prgPageLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgPageLoading);
        btnBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);

        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        web.loadUrl(myURL);

        btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                String webUrl = web.getUrl();
                String webTitle = web.getTitle();

                final String p0 = "KYFB Share:";
                final String p1 = "Kentucky Farm Bureau";
                final String p2 = "'Big On Commitment.'";



                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, webTitle);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, p0 + "\n\n" + webUrl + "\n\n\n" +
                   p1 + "\n" + p2 +  "\n\n");

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"));

            }
        });

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(web.canGoBack()){
                    web.goBack();
                } else 
                    finish();
            }
        });

        btnForward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(web.canGoForward()){
                    web.goForward();
                }
            }
        });

        final Activity act = this;
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView webview, int progress){

                act.setProgress(progress*100);
                prgPageLoading.setProgress(progress);

            }


        });

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted( WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon ) {

                super.onPageStarted( web, url, favicon );
                prgPageLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished( WebView view, String url ) {

                super.onPageFinished( web, url );
                prgPageLoading.setProgress(0);
                prgPageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }   
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                 Toast.makeText(act, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {

                if(url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp") || url.endsWith(".avi")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i); //warning no error handling will cause force close if no media player on phone.
                    return true;
                }

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            });



    }



}
```

Comment: Can you post some code from the webview rendering piece?

Comment: Are you sure the server sends the same response and does not look at the user agent string to send a smaller version to mobiles?

Comment: I'm pretty sure.  The site looks like it should in my stock Android browser.  It only leaves elements out when it is in a web view in my app.

Comment: And the web view sends the same user agent string? I doubt that.

Comment: I added this:
web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
but it still doesn't load the site correctly.

Comment: I also tried:
web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Chrome");
That loads the full desktop version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

The server inspects the user agent header string and sends a smaller version of the page when it thinks the request comes from a mobile phone.

It seems, this logic is not working perfectly.